# Exception caught by @ExceptionHandler is not recorded by MetricsWebFilter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

Trying to migrate from web-mvc to webflux+coroutines. Faced a problem with `http.server.requests` metric recording.

With web-mvc, when using @RestController, @RestControllerAdvice with multiple @ExceptionHandler, I got exception classes recorded in `exception` tag of metric `http.server.requests`.
Like so `http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="CustomException",method="POST",outcome="CLIENT_ERROR",status="400",uri="/v1/users",} 1.0`

However, this refuses to work as expected with webflux (spring boot 2.3.4). I used same annotated components.
`http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="POST",outcome="CLIENT_ERROR",status="400",uri="/v1/users",} 1.0`
In this case there is a call to MetricsWebFilter.onSuccess(...), which does not have exception parameter.
Desired `exception` tag is filled only on exceptions uncaught by @RestControllerAdvice. This may seem like a reasonable thing to do, but it is unexpected and complicates service monitoring for me.

Maybe there is a way to achieve old behaviour?

Comment: could this be an ordering issue? Is it possible for you to debug your application and see which order invocation happens between the MetricsWebFilter and ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver. If the exception resolution happens before the metrics filter then the metrics filter will see no exception at all.

Comment: As I can see, in any case (mvc/webflux) metrics-filter finishes its job after exception resolving. However, in mvc context the handled exception seems to be residing in request context somehow, and metrics-filter extracts it. As for webflux, I did not succeed overriding order on MetricsWebFilter bean.. Feeling like I should probably open an issue for that after all.

Comment: for reference, I have used a custom implementation of `WebExceptionHandler` to handle exception resolution and this is applied after the `MetricsWebFilter` which allows the exception tags to be correct on the metrics. Opening an issue sounds like a good next step. Best of luck

Comment: opened spring boot issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23795